# How to embed an integer in a macro string?

Tags: c, macros, stringification

My first time seeing stringification and token pasting.  I feel like it could be a good tool for this macro:

```
#define MY_NUMBER   3
#define MY_STRING   "the number three: ##MY_NUMBER"
printf("%s\n", MY_STRING);
```

should output:

```
the number three: 3
```

Comment: What's wrong with `printf("%s %d\n", MY_STRING, MY_NUMBER)`???

Comment: The printf is just for testing.  The real question is meant to be creating the macro.

Comment: Preprocessor operators (# and ##) do not work inside quoted string literals. You cannot use token concatenation to concatenate string literals, either; only individual tokens. (However, you can concatenate two string literals by just writing them one after another: `"Hello, " "world!"`). And finally, you can only use the stringify operator (#) on macro parameters. @alk: The linked answer is good but I fear that it is not really an answer to this confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
#define S_(x) #x
#define S(x) S_(x)

#define MY_NUMBER   3
#define MY_STRING   "the number three: " S(MY_NUMBER)
```

Comment: Why didn't you write `#define S(x) #x` directly?

Comment: @Nasr if `S(MY_NUMBER)` then you get  `"MY_NUMBER"`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, this works, but I don't understand why?  Can you explain a bit more on what that second S_(x) may be doing?

Comment: @tarabyte There is a need to call indirectly for make `MY_NUMBER` expand `3`. `#var` will stringified `var` to `"var"`.